# How can I implement an interface in my JavaFX Controller?

Tags: java, class, javafx, interface

I have an interface for posting system messages to the GUI but the way I am doing it causes a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION on the class that tries to use the interface method(not the one that implements it)

```
public interface SystemMessage {
    void postMessage(String outText);
}
```

In my controller i implement this interface and use it to post a message to the GUI

```
public class MainController implements SystemMessage {
    @FXML
    public DialogPane systemMessage;

    @Override
    public void postMessage(String outText) {
        systemMessage.setContentText(outText);
    }
}
```

From Main.java I call some helper classes to do some background work (i am not to threading yet so excuse that everything is on the main thread)

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/entry.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    this.mainController = loader.getController();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
    initializeSync();
}

private void initializeSync() {
    //Each of these perform several function on initialization
    Identity identity = new Identity();
    String[] args = null;
    Api api = new Api();
    api.Get(args);
    SqLite db = new SqLite();
}
```

So, in my Identity Class upon initialization i try to use the interface to post a message but I get NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.

```
public class Identity {
    private String machineId = null;
    public String statusText = null;

    SystemMessage systemMessage;// Trying to instantiate the system message interface??

    public Identity(){
        systemMessage.postMessage("Checking Machine Identity");
        //..//
    }
    //..//
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that your concern be specific to JavaFX.

You need to set the dependency to `SystemMessage` when you create an `Identity` object.
Replace :

```
Identity identity = new Identity();
```

by :

```
...
MainController mainController = ... // retrieve it with fxmlLoader if required
Identity identity = new Identity(mainController);
```

And change the `Identity` constructor so that it takes a `SystemMessage` parameter :

```
public Identity(SystemMessage systemMessage){
    this.systemMessage = systemMessage;
    systemMessage.postMessage("Checking Machine Identity");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.. I am trying to understand. So, I need to reference the fxmlloader which has the controller attached to it and pass it to the Identity class so that it knows where or how to use the interface?

Comment: Also, see my edit.. In my main file I have a mainController object that I set up in start(). can i use this throughout the main to pass to each class that gets instantiated?

Comment: I figured it out... I was able to user your code in my start() method and then pass the ("reference"?) to the other classes!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: You are welcome. Before your edit I didn't know if you had a variable referencing the `MainController` object in the scope of the `initializeSync()`  method. So in the doubt, in my answer,  I retrieved it first. But as you have it, you have just to use it indeed :)  I would have specified this point in my answer sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As @silversunhunter answered correctly pass the actual `mainController` up to `Identity`:

```
    initializeSync(this.mainController);
}

private void initializeSync(SystemMessage systemMessage) {
    Identity identity = new Identity(systemMessage);
```